# iOS - Unable to add image objects to a NSMutableArray

Tags: ios

I am trying to add images that have been stored to a NSMutableArray. As loop through, I can see each image but when I try to add them to my images array, I get a count of 0.

I have the following code:

.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class Schedule;

@interface PMCViewController : UIViewController  <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *images;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) Schedule *schedule;

- (IBAction)OpenAdmin:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)OpenSchedules:(id)sender;

@end
```

and them in my implementation file:

.m

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {

[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];

NSArray *schedules = [[ScheduleStore sharedStore] allSchedules];

scrollView.delegate = self;
scrollView.scrollEnabled = YES;
scrollView.pagingEnabled = YES;

int scrollWidth = 120;
scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth,80); 

int xOffset = 0;

for (int i=0; i < [schedules count]; i++) {

    Schedule *selectedSchedule = [schedules objectAtIndex:i];
    NSString *ik = [selectedSchedule imageKey];

    UIImageView *img = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
    //img.bounds = CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50);
    //img.frame = CGRectMake(5+xOffset, 0, 50, 50);
    //img.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    //img.image = [[ScheduleImageStore sharedStore] imageForKey:ik];

    [img setBounds:CGRectMake(10, 10, 50, 50)];
    [img setFrame:CGRectMake((5+xOffset), 0, 50, 50)];
    [img setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [img setImage:[[ScheduleImageStore sharedStore] imageForKey:ik]];

    [images addObject:img];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(scrollWidth+xOffset,50); 
    [scrollView addSubview:[images objectAtIndex:i]];

    xOffset += 70;

}
NSLog(@"Number of img added: %i",[images count]);

[[self scheduleView] reloadData];
}
```

I tried both dot notation and regular notation but that didn't make a difference. I can't seem to add items to the images array. Could this be a memory issue? Any ideas?

Comment: `images` is a `weak` property, how are you assigning it?  Where is this mutable array coming from?  Did you remember to alloc/init it?

Comment: Ahh, I feel foolish. Of course, and thanks for the 2nd pair of eyes.

Comment: When debugging follow the evidence.  Adding images doesn't work so put a breakpoint at where you add images to the array and check the variables.  At this point it would have been obvious since images would have been nil.  So when something goes wrong, don't panic, just follow the bread crumbs.  The more you do this the easier it gets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to initialise `images` array.